# mysql query between two times

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, between

I would like to query a mySQL table to pull out data between two times from January 10, like between 16:00 to 17:00. But in my database, I used to store date & time in **strtotime formate** and I should do it in Mysql.

Please help. Thank you!

Database image
https://pasteboard.co/HVPMdqF.png

Sample Code:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE loginTime between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-10 16:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-10 18:00')
```

But query not work.

Comment: What is the type of the column `loginTime`?

Comment: "I would like to query a mySQL table to pull out data between two times from January 10, like between 16:00 to 17:00" that data looks like UNIXTIMESTAMPS it looks you query that data more or less correct if you change `2019-01-10 18:00` into `2019-01-10 17:00` .. What's the problem or what's your question? Or do you want to store DATETIME formats (like `2019-01-10 16:00`) in your database instead?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(loginTime) between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-10 16:00') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2019-01-10 18:00')

Comment: As Raymond mentioned, your code should work.  Please [edit] your question to provide more information about what doesn't work.

Comment: loginTime type is varchar

Answer (score 1):

> loginTime type is varchar

That's where you're trouble starts. You should redesign the table an use a proper date/time type.

Meanwhile you essentially got two options.

1. Convert `logintime` to a Unix timestamp too.

   ```
   WHERE unix_timestamp(logintime) BETWEEN unix_timestamp('2019-01-10 16:00')
                                           AND unix_timestamp('2019-01-10 17:00')
   ```
2. Or compare strings.

   ```
   WHERE logintime BETWEEN '2019-01-10 16:00'
                           AND '2019-01-10 17:00'
   ```

Both require `logintime` to only store well formed date/time representations to work properly. For 1. there are some formats, that `unix_timestamp()` recognizes. For 2. it has to be exactly `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI`.